# Temporary creating bitmaps in Android then deleting them

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, delete-file

So I am working on a project where if a manager registers a user he gets an email with a QR code (bitmap). The QR code is saved in cache. I want the QR code removed after the QR code is sent to the user, but a "cache" folder gets created (also shows up in gallery), and the image itself gets deleted but it remains there ( you cant see it, but its there as a grey square).
Any idea how to remove the created folder and the created bitmap compeletely?

My code:

```
 BitmapSaver(Context mContext){
    this.mContext=mContext;
    this.cache = new DiskBasedCache(mContext.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
}

public static File saveImageToExternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        destFolder =context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
//  myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
 //   myDir.mkdirs();
    long n = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    //file2 = new File(destFolder);
    file = new File(destFolder+"/"+fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        Log.i("path",destFolder+"/"+fname);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder+"/"+fname);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    url = Uri.parse(path);
                    Log.i("External",url.toString());
                }
            });

    return file;
}
```

In Activity after email is sent:

```
BitmapSaver bms = new BitmapSaver(RegisterActivity.this);
     bms.saveImageToExternalStorage(RegisterActivity.this, bitmap);


bms.file.delete();
```

Comment: You should re-scan the file with MediaScannerConnection after delete, and actually you don't need to scan the file while adding, because it will notify the device that the image is ready to use by other applications.

Comment: Thanx, that worked.

Comment: See my answer for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know what `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` does. It will update the file information to the current device, so other applications like gallery, file explorer, etc, can show the correct file information and content.

From your code, when you are saving the temporary file, you are also scanning it, because your app has changed the corresponding file, which is creating the file to be exact. So the file will be available to the other applications right away. But, since the file location is in your application cache directory, it will not accessible by other applications. Usually you must restart your device to update the file information if you don't call `MediaScanner.scanFile`. If you are creating a temporary file, I think **you don't need to call `MediaScanner.scanFile`**, since you will delete it right away.
Then after delete, you also need to re-scan the file again, so other applications will know that the file has been deleted.

Also, despite of using `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` directly, if you are supporting android version < KitKat, you should broadcast with intent action `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` instead. And I also recommend that you are broadcasting the data directly, because from my experience `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` failed from one of my test devices.

```
Intent mediaScanIntent;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
} else {
    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath);
    mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, fileUri);
}
context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```